# Excel VBA - How to select the whole table of borders

Tags: vba, excel, range, border

i am very new to Excel VB. I am hoping you can assist with my problem.

I have several tables like this
[image: this]

The tables can be edited such as by inserting new rows, etc by the user.

I want to highlight and copy the latest table (the one at the very last row) and paste it at the next available space, 3 rows down. 
I managed to do this, but I can only highlight and copy the cells with data. So should there be an empty row in the middle of the table, or an empty last row with borders, it would not copy correctly, as shown here:

[image: here]

I do still need to copy everything within the borders including empty rows, but I lack the skills and knowledge to do so. I hope you can assist.

The following is my code:

```
Sub CopyPaste()
    LastRow = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    FirstColumn = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext).Column
    LastColumn = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
    BelowLastName = Cells.Find("", After:=Cells(LastRow, FirstColumn), SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row


    Cells(BelowLastName, FirstColumn).Select 'This selects C5 (refer image)
    Selection.Offset(-1).Select 'This selects C4 (refer image)
    Range(Selection, Cells(LastRow, LastColumn)).Select 'This highlights whole table
    Selection.Copy

    Cells(LastRow, FirstColumn).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(3).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: I recommend to use [formatted tables](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Format-an-Excel-table-6789619f-c889-495c-99c2-2f971c0e2370?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1) for this use case. Then you can access and copy the whole formatted table at once without searching for values or borders.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I will definitely keep your suggestion in mind. If I do need to use borders still, can you recommend any ways to search for the entire table of borders?

Comment: yes, use formatted tables. Otherwise no. [Here](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/6/20/the-vba-guide-to-listobject-excel-tables) is a nice guide what you can do with tables and VBA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Sub x()

Dim rEnd As Range, rStart As Range, i As Long

Set rEnd = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)

Do While rEnd.Offset(i).Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous
    i = i - 1
Loop

Set rStart = rEnd.Offset(i + 1)

Range(rStart, rEnd).Resize(, 8).Copy rEnd.Offset(3)

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. However, It does not get the empty rows as well. I will keep your code in mind should I need it for other tasks though.

Comment: Which empty rows?

Comment: Refer to the second picture, there are empty rows in the second table. Can you modify your code to copy the whole table, including those empty rows of borders as well? Cheers

Comment: OK I see now, so it's all the block of cells with borders.

Comment: Amended code above - please give it a go and let me know how you get on.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Your code kind of works. Just one thing though. Is it possible to get the block of cells, regardless of the border's thickness? Currently your code only works on the thin line border, while disregarding the medium thickness border.

Comment: I've made another change which seems to work when I tested it.

Comment: Excellent! This will do. Thanks a lot for your help. I really appreciate it.